# Regex match last sentence in a paragraph with decimal numbers

Tags: regex

Given the sentence:

> Examination shows mild swelling around the left eye. Her left eye does
>   not move past midline on far left gaze but moves normally when looking
>   to the right. Without treatment, which of the following findings is
>   most likely to occur in this patient?

How can I match the last sentence, even if the last sentence includes a decimal number, such as below? Assume that the last sentence always ends in a question mark.

> Examination shows mild swelling around the left eye. Her left eye does
>   not move past midline on far left gaze but moves normally when looking
>   to the right. Which of the following findings is
>   most likely to occur in a patient with a BGL of 11.2 mmol/L without treatment?

My current solution is this, which matches the last sentence in the first example, but it doesn't tolerate decimals.

```
(\. )([ A-Za-z0-9\-\"\'\(\)\,\:\;\<\>\/\\]+)(\?)
```

Ideal solution should result in the following strings respectively:

> Without treatment, which of the following findings is most likely to
>   occur in this patient?

AND

> Which of the following findings is most likely to occur in a patient
>   with a BGL of 11.2 mmol/L without treatment?

Comment: Your `(\?)` seems to imply that the last sentence will always end in a question mark, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'll make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sentence-terminating periods are followed by spaces, you can alternate with your big character set, and a period which is *not* followed by a space, using negative lookahead:

```
|\.(?! )
```

Also note that most things don't need to be escaped in a character set - only the regex delimiters (`/`, often) and literal backslashes need to be escaped.

```
(\. )(?:[ a-z\d-"'(),:;<>\/\\]|\.(?! ))+(\?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/j2bufP/1